# Best WordPress plugins to learn how to build WordPress plugins

Tags: wordpress

Not sure this question is appropriate for stack overflow
but on the other hand I'm not quite sure where else to
ask it.

I am learning about about WordPress plugins and would like
to ask for recommendations as to which WordPress plugins to
download and analyse so as to learn by inspecting their
source code. What are some of the best ones that would
do for instructional purposes?

Thanks.

Comment: I am also loking for plugin ideas as I would like to write a plugin but don't know what it should do. If anyone wants to write a plugin together or contribute some ideas as to what to write please let me know.

Comment: I think you want to learn plugin development from scratch. Here you can : 
 http://atiblog.com/wordpress-plugin-development/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you are asking for something that other developers online cannot give you such as walking you through web based languages. You need to read documentations in order to understand them or go for classes.

Secondly Wordpress is open for you to develop for. If you did research it on Google, or any other search engine, you would find pages like this:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API

Thirdly come back to Stackoverflow if you have code but it's not working so other developers can try help you with!

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting stuck with building your plugin, I often first develop the plugin as a function (in my wordpress theme's functions.php file or as an include) to get to grips with the internal functions and calls I might need to use before then translating it into a completely separate plugin for use on other projects.

It might seem like slightly strange approach, but when I was first starting out with WordPress plugins, using the functions.php file to quickly setup and run my plugins really helps as its typically already setup with the core WP load files needed to hook into all the right areas. This then allows you to gently move your code across into a separate plugin and test each segment too!

The Codex (as posted above) and the NetTuts site are two very good resources for learning more about plugins, but just try diving in with a function you want to create and customise, start small and build it up!

Answer (score 1):

If the codex is a bit intimidating, you might also consider starting with this great tutorial. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/creating-a-custom-wordpress-plugin-from-scratch/